# SDWebImage completed: completion block not called

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I've a string in which I've comma separated images URL and I'm splitting it into array as: `let imagesLinks = imageLins.components(separatedBy: ",")`. Next by using for loop I'm storing the downloaded images in an `imagesArray` as:

```
for imag in imagesLinks
        {
            let img = UIImageView()

            let activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView.init(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
            let refreshBarButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: activityIndicator)
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refreshBarButton
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()

            let imgURL: URL = URL(string: "\(baseReportImageURL)\(imag)")!

            img.sd_setImage(with: imgURL, completed: {
                (image, error, cacheType, url) in
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                imagesArray.append(image!)
                self.photoCollection.reloadData()
            })

//            img.sd_setImage(with: imgURL, placeholderImage: nil,options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
//                //activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
//                imagesArray.append(image!)
//                self.photoCollection.reloadData()
//            })

        }
```

Now the issue is that it send the call but did the `completed:` block is not called. If I go back and push the view controller again it goes in the `completed:` block instantly. So my assumption is that it might have downloaded and cache the images and when it is again called it check the images are already downloaded so it run the block at that time. **But why is it skipping it for the first time?**

Secondly I'm calling a custom function from `viewDidLoad()`  in a custom function called `func downloadAndUpdateImagesAarray()` inside this I've the for loop. Also `self.photoCollection.reloadData()` is a collection view on which the cell only havean image.

Comment: which version of SDWebImage you are using ?

Comment: @PulkitKumarSingh it's 4.1.2

Comment: Did you find the answer ?